# in xslt2.0 , how to add extra minute value to existing time stamp

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

I had a time stamp in my input xml as below

**2012-01-19T21:36:33.085+01:00**

now i want to add some minute value to it . the different values of minutes are as below
30,-30,60,-60

Is there any xslt function to do this addition and give the output as of type xs:dateTime

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can cast your minutes as a duration and then add/subtract. (Subtract if it's a negative number.)

Example...

**XML Input**

```
<test>2012-01-19T21:36:33.085+01:00</test>
```

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" extension-element-prefixes="xs">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:param name="minutesToAdd" select="30" as="xs:integer"/>

    <xsl:template match="/*">
        <results>
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="0 > $minutesToAdd">
                    <xsl:value-of select="xs:dateTime(.) - xs:dayTimeDuration(concat('PT',abs($minutesToAdd),'M'))"/>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:value-of select="xs:dateTime(.) + xs:dayTimeDuration(concat('PT',$minutesToAdd,'M'))"/>
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </results>  
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output**

```
<results>2012-01-19T22:06:33.085+01:00</results>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
        xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
        xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
        >

<xsl:template name="main">
 <xsl:value-of select="xs:dateTime('2012-01-19T21:36:33.085+01:00') + 
               xs:dayTimeDuration('PT0H30M')"/>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

produces

```
2012-01-19T22:06:33.085+01:00
```

Comment: but where you add the different value of minutes to the time stamp does PT0H30M means +30 min  or - 30 , what if i need to add +20  or -20, could you please explain it ?

Comment: yes that is P for period (duration) with T ime component  0 Hours 30 Minutes